# Need UDF to Compare two values of 2 different contexts and give the count based on successful comparison in SAP PI

Tags: java, sap-pi

I am facing problem in UDF. Please help me out.

From each context `E1EDL24` we need to take `POSNR` value and match it with the first another context `E1EDL37`/`E1EDL44` `POSNR` value.  If it matches make 'count' as 1. Then check the next first context `E1EDL37`/`E1EDL44` `POSNR` value and if we get the match 'count' will increase by 1 and so on.
If no matches 'count' will be zero.

I have tried writing UDF it is iterating only the number of times the input is given.

UDF :

```
**int flag,count=0;
for(int i=0;i<POSNR.length;i++)
{
flag=0;
for(int j=0;j<POSNR1.length;j++)
{
if(POSNR[i].equals(POSNR1[j]))
{
result.addValue("1");
flag=1;
break;
}
}
if(flag==0)
result.addValue("0");
}**
```

Comment: Why tags `javascript` and `php`?